# Weight loss plateau

Tags: weight-loss, diet, workout-routines, workout, plateau

I am desperate. I've always heard that when you hit a plateau you can adjust your workouts or your eating habits. I've done BOTH, and seen absolutely no progress in my weight loss. I started out at an all time high weight of 133, (I am a 5' flat female) and a few weeks ago I managed to get down to a very shaky 126, where I knew I would probably gain back a few lbs in the near future. I was stable at 128 for nearly 3 weeks, and now am back to 132. Here's exactly what I ate today, and this is what I always eat like, (Used to just be more of everything, and I used to eat a LOT of gluten) but lately I've really cut back on amounts in my attempt to lose weight. Everything in my house is made from scratch with very high quality ingredients. I actually wonder if I eat too well.

Brekki:

Oatmeal with honey. (Big breakfast, normally I just have toast)

Lunch brought from home:

cucumber slices

whole strawberries

chicken soup

I haven't had dinner yet, but last night I had the same chicken soup and strawberries. 
I haven't been eating any snacks between meals for the last few months, but today I was so furious with the scale I ate two slices of homemade bread and some chocolate. This is the first time I've ever done that. Its also the first gluten I've eaten in a month and now I'm feeling rather sick. 
I'm also in such a rotten mood I'm not working out right now, when I usually do for around an hour. 
This is a part of my workout from yesterday just to give you a taste of what I like to do:

front squat and weighted lunge
10-9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1

2 rounds
250 single unders

modified WOD
5 rounds 
30 pushups
40 butterfly sit ups
50 weighted squats

I also did a glute and arm workout. This was an easy day. I think that I work out HARD. 
What the @#$% is wrong with me???
I've worked out for years, not with the intent to lose weight, mainly in training for track, and never lost weight from any of that. Am I just destined to be one weight? I don't even think I've been changing my body consistency. No muscle gains or anything. Actually maybe a little bit in my arms, and maybe if I'm lucky, I'm seeing something in my stomach. I don't want to look like a supermodel (Gross) I just want to be happy with my body. 
My mom said I was fat, sparking all of this @#$$.

Comment: *Only from what you've written* makes it seem like you're not eating enough which can cause the body to adapt in the short term to not lose weight (muscle is easier to break down than fat in a very hypo-caloric diet). Do you track what you eat in any fashion? That's always my first go-to when people have trouble with losing weight.

Comment: but the thing is that I've always worked out like this (or harder) and I've always been gaining instead of losing. The only thing that I've really changed is my diet... I have a good memory if that counts as tracking... I'm back at 126ish, but I always go back up instead of going down. I always eat until I'm satisfied... I actually usually eat more for dinner than is listed... throw in some salad and walnuts or dried fruit. What is tracking what you eat supposed to accomplish? Snacking without realizing? Tracking calories? I def don't want to lose muscle.

Comment: There isn't enough information to offer any sound advice -only general.  How is your blood pressure? Do you have any disabilities? Have you had any surgeries or injuries that I should know about? Can you get your hands on some dumbbells with adjustable weights? How much time do you have to devote to your fitness a day? Could you describe your general diet in greater detail? Revise the question with these details please.

Comment: Also, include your resting heart rate in Beats Per Minute (BPM). Rest with very little activity for 30+ minutes (i.e. sitting, laying down -best), then, without changing position, take your pulse either on your left wrist or throat and count for exactly 90 seconds or two minutes. Do the appropriate math for BPM. See: http://www.topendsports.com/testing/heart-rate-resting-chart.htm 

Tell me how many modified push-ups you can do. See: http://sportsmedicine.about.com/od/fitnessevalandassessment/a/PushUpTest.htm

Comment: To estimate your body fat% see: https://www.healthstatus.com/calculate/body-fat-percentage-calculator It is not the most accurate method but it will get us close. I know I asking a lot but I'm very limited on what I can do without this info. If you're not able to do everything then just do the best you can. Also tell us your fitness goals. I know you want to lose body fat but what else is important to you? Is competing in track still important to you?

Comment: I have a good blood pressure and healthy heart rate according to my doctor, but I can't remember what they were specifically. I would guess that I am on the higher side of average as heart disease, high cholesterol, etc; run in my family. I am healthy, beyond my struggle with shin splints. The only injury I've ever had in my life is a slight sprained ankle and a few concussions. I do have dumbbells, but they aren't adjustable. I don't really get into variety in my diet, so every day is about the same. Until recently I've always eaten a lot of carbs, fruit, veg, meat, some dairy. I eat anything

Comment: I like the idea of paleo, but I can't pull it off right now. I eat around 2 gluten items a day, maybe a bite of diary every few days. I eat a lot of meat. I love nuts. Protein bars are my guilty snacks, but I gained a lot of weight from eating protein bars a few years ago... I love dark chocolate. I have 2/3 fruit/veg and 1/3 meat or something else for lunch everyday. Breakfast and dinner can be anything. On the weekends I usually end up eating out at least once, maybe pizza or else I always order salads and wraps. I try to avoid 'real' deserts, I might eat some dark chocolate or dried fruit.

Comment: I used the navy body fat calculator, and scored 26%... It didn't strike me as very accurate tho, because the measurements were pretty vague.  Honestly I want to just dominate at track and sport meets. I MTB, so I need strong legs. I to shave 3 secs off my 200m. I want to add another 2 feet at least to my long jump. I want to be able to put at least 150 on my legs. I want to lift 25 on each arm, and do 35 lbs kettle bell swings. I can do 100 modified push ups without stopping. I can probably only do 20 regular ones. I can plank for 8 minutes.  I can drop 200 air squats.

Comment: I only have 1 year of track left... my interest is flagging, but when I compete I still want to win. I want to have muscle tone. I want to lose fat and never see it again. I want to feel good on the inside. I want to be able to smash my friends and competition right out of the water.  My friends are all boys, and I still train/compete with them. I'm not sure if that's really smart or not... but girls either don't try or aren't interested. I really want to be able to do pull ups. I haven't done one since 6th grade.

Answer (score 1):

**You're doing great!** Keep it up! For your best health and fitness, don't worry so much about weight. Worry more about body fat and how you feel. Muscle weights much more that fat because of its density and water. Another factors contributing to your weight is how hydrated you are. The more active you are the more water you'll need. Because of these things you may actually gain weight from proper diet and exercise.

Oatmeal is great, bread and chocolate, not so much. Really, if you can see some shape in you stomach than you're doing great! Don't listen to your mom just laugh at her idiocy and tell her to shut up! Seriously, mothers should never say such things to their daughters. I don't want to start a conflict but really this kind of remark from a mother leads to insecurity and eating disorders.

**Body Fat and how you feel:** If you had a higher than your desired body fat and you keep up the good work, you may notice your cloths becoming looser and you skin may sag a bit (don't worry it will correct its self). Don't measure your progress by the scale but instead measure it with calipers and other methods of measuring body fat. Also, listen to your body and how you feel. You may notice that you can lift more, run longer, have more energy etc. Let these things drive you! But be careful not to over do it, only you can know what this means but in other words don't push yourself into injury. I'm not sure how new you are to working out but you sound like you know a bit about it. You may know that consistency is key to personal fitness. you're not going to become fit overnight. Any diet will not produce immediate results. Anyone trying to convince you otherwise is just trying to sell you something. Don't Buy it!

**Diet:** Whatever you do don't get sucked in to dieting fads. Many of these only produce short-term results and will wear you out. Like juicing diets that make you have diarrhea. This will make you loose water weight and result in short term colon damage, an short-term inability to absorb nutrients, and leave you feeling tired and unable to go to the gym. Don't starve yourself as your body need natural sources of nutrients to keep you going. Just eat healthy. Eat lots of vegetables, some fruits, less carbohydrate loaded foods, and plenty of meats as some dairy is okay. Meats and lower card veggies are loaded with great nutrients. Just 3 ounces of meat has more nutrients twice that of most fruits and veggies. (I'd post more links but sadly I cannot do this at the time. Use google to verify the info I stated.)

See [Nutrient facts.org](http://nutritionfacts.org/) for more info.

It's okay to cheat once in a while and have some chocolate and ice cream and such. The point is don't make a habit out of it and go with out it at more often than not.

**Fitness:** Strength training will burn more kcals and sooner than cardio/pulmonary (Not vascular, this never made seance to me.) workouts. Keep your fitness routine well rounded. For women, it is important to do bone strengthening activities to prevent osteoporosis later in life. Track helps with this but weights and strength training should be utilized as well. You don't have to get big muscles and strength training will not inevitably do this unless you aim for it. You'll of course still want to do you're cardio/pulmonary workouts as well, just keep them balanced.

You're young, don't stress too much about this stuff. Sure, build up good fitness habits but don't let them get you down. Good luck to you!

Comment: The trouble IS fat. I have a high body fat percentage... can I load photos on here?? My stomach fat sucks. I know that I HAVE to lose weight for this to go away. I am fit, but at this point I'm taking that for granted, and now I want to see my fitness. I tell people I love to workout and they instantly say yeah right. I include everything in my workout, and I am very conscious of the fact that I am a woman, I started working out because my mom... darn her... suggested that I make sure I have strong hips. Do I ever need to drink more than a gallon of water on a normal day?

Comment: I feel great, but my clothes are never getting looser. Once again I wish I could post pix on here... I am self trained and sometimes I find it difficult to gauge my progress inwardly and outwardly. I'm not starving myself. I try to avoid carbs and dairy more than anything else, fruits, veg, and meat are what makes me feel good, so its what I try to eat...  I don't have calipers, but my school is going to get some. The only dieting fad I've ever considered or vaguely trusted is paleo. If I struggle with my weight now, it can only go downhill from here.

Comment: You need to be physically assessed. We cannot do that for you here. Women generally have a higher body fat percentage than men. This is healthy. Don't compare yourself with professional female athletes. Consult a doctor, fitness instructor, and a nutritionist with your specific goals and workout a plan to achieve then.

Comment: The fact is that some anorexics think that they're fat and will impulsively lie about it. I'm not suggesting that you are. Nevertheless, if you're on a highschool track team, reasonably I hope you can understand that we may find it hard to believe that you're very much overweight. DISCLAIMER: the diets and exercises I recommended are general guidelines, every individual is different. Perhaps if you outlined your specific goals we could point you in the right direction. If your goal is simply to lower your body fat then focus on strength training as this will lower your body fat the most.

Comment: Why do you avoid dairy? Are you lactose intolerant?

Comment: I am not anorexic. I am not over weight, my BMI is pre-obese, around 25. I just have high personal standards. I want to lose 10 lbs, because I know that will eliminate most of my stomach fat. I weight around 130.  My heroes are athletes and Olympians. People say if you're not a professional athlete, you can't be like one, but I question that. I am really short, so this sits on me differently than if I was even an inch taller. dairy = fat for me, and I don't like it. I had really bad allergies when I was little, among them dairy, and all processed food.

Comment: BMI is not a good indicator for health or body fat. BMI does not take lean muscle mass into account. At one point, for example, I was down to 5% body fat but because I had a lot of lean muscle mass BMI indicated that I was morbidly obese.

Comment: I believe as you do that a person can approach the level of professional athletes fitness but it is not necessarily healthy or required. BMI = Bullshit Mass Index. You are right, being short will make you look bulkier. BMI will make look worse even if you have an athletic build. You gotta know what your current fitness assessment report says and what your body fat percentage actually is before you can gauge your progress and design a fitness plan to achieve your goals. This sounds like the next logical step based on the fact that you're already very fit and now want to fine tune your body.

Comment: what is the best way to assess my fitness?

Comment: There are several methods but basically anything that measures your 1RM in 3 major muscle groups for strength, your endurance (usually measured by running on a treadmill), VO2max, resting and maximum heart rate and calculate your hearts stroke volume, blood pressure, and body composition including accurate body fat calculators. There are probably a few that I'm missing but that should cover most. There are several different methods of calculating body fat and some are very inaccurate. Bio-electrical Impedance is the most convenient but isn't very accurate. Some can be as much as +/-15%.

Comment: For body fat, old fashion calipers are the easiest and most accurate as long as they are using the right calculations. They still have a margin of error around +/-5%. Other methods can be as little as +/-1% but they can be expensive and very inconvenient. Most gyms will offer an assessment but they don't usually take all these tests and sometimes they do them wrong. But you can still get a general idea. Some doctors will do these as well but most doctors are only concerned about general health and not as much as preventative or physical fitness.

Comment: FYI: the error margins I posted vary and the percentage indicated is as follows: if a test shows 20% body fat and the error margin is +/-15%, then 20x0.15 = +/-3% so you could be %17 or 23% body fat. The  Bio-electrical Impedance that you just hold in your had are not as accurate but the ones you stand on barefoot and hold on to handles are more accurate.

Comment: I'll add another answer, time allowing, that is more inline with what you're looking for based on these comments...

Answer (score -1):

You should do cardio exercises. If you build up your cardio fitness, you should be able to run for an hour or longer at a fast pace (13 km/h or faster). You'll then burn more than 1000 Kcal per day. You should actually eat a lot more to get there, try to eat a lot more whole grain bread, brown rice and whole grain pasta. The total calorie intake should be large enough to allow you to run fast for a long time. You should not worry about weight gain, as the focus should be on  building up your cardio fitness. You'll find that even with a much higher calorie intake, your weight will not increase or even decrease a bit, provided you exercise hard enough and only eat healthy foods (only whole grain products, a lot of vegetables, at least 400 grams per day).

You can also think of it this way. If you start to run then the reason why your cardio fitness will improve is fundamentally because your body will do whatever is necessary to facility your new activity. The biochemical changes are not the fundamental reason because these mechanisms were developed as a result of evolution. Now, an activity like running would only be done by our ancestors or other animals because of survival needs. Running more switches on all sorts of processes that enhance the capability of an animal to be able to run well. And that includes weight loss too.

Comment: these answers directly contradict each other, and I'm inclined to agree with the first.

Comment: I don't mean to write you off but I am a competing sprinter/long jumper. I know what I want to do to my body and right now running for an hour regularly would undo something I've worked for since I was very young.

Comment: I suppose I just shot myself in the foot and decided I want to look huge. Really I just want to lose the stomach fat. Maybe once I quit track for good I'll look into the cardio aspect more. I do sprints regularly, this can take around an hour for technical training, but then it's competition season and I'm definitely not concerned with my looks. I've always had a carb based diet before this, with while grains, and lots of fruits and veg. I've gained over 15 lbs in the past year, so I believe a diet like that will make me look like sludge.

Comment: I do work really hard right now. I've been well rewarded for my endeavors,  winning plenty of podium time, and a few cash prizes. Its my diet that needs the most help I think. 'the capability of an animal to be able to run more.' that's lovely, but I gained weight running for an hour, and you make it sound like running only helps running. I also got stress fractures and shin splints. I have good running shoes and form, it was just too much stress. I have a new bike, that's soft cardio. Sorry my comments are rude. I guess I'm just looking for self justification.

Comment: You could consider doing high intensity cardio (HIT). You do have to run at sufficient speed, it shouldn't be jogging speed, so doing HIT for half an hour or so coud help. [Frank Medrano](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvJHw64fxgQ) also does HIT cardio to keep his fat percentage low.